# Ajax CalendarExtender inserted in a gridview are populated in the same row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, calendarextender

I've a problem with the CalendarExtender ajax.
I've a gridview with a calendar in a templatefield but when i run the application and, for example i've 5 data rows, my calendars are all at the firstrow.
Somebody can explain me why?
There is my code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvFeatureCustomer" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ClientIDRowSuffix="Id" OnRowDataBound="dtgdResult_RowDataBound" ClientIDMode="Static"
            ShowHeader="false" CssClass="datagrid" Style="width: 100%;" OnRowCommand="gvFeatureCustomer_RowCommand"
            OnRowDeleting="gvFeatureCustomer_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nome" FooterText="Nome" SortExpression="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlName" ClientIDMode="Predictable" runat="server" DataValueField="id"
                            DataTextField="Name" Style="width: 100%;">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Valore" FooterText="Valore" SortExpression="Value">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" CssClass="auto-feature"
                            OnTextChanged="txtValue_TextChanged" Style="width: 100%"></asp:TextBox>
                        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender99" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtValue" runat="server">
                        </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" FooterText="Delete" Visible="true" HeaderStyle-Width="25"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DeleteImageUrl="~/images/delete2.png" ButtonType="Image"
                    ShowDeleteButton="true" />

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you accept the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

attribute from your `GridView` definition, because if you use it, all your `TextBox` controls will have the same ID, "txtValue". The `CalendarExtender` controls will find the first value (which is on the first row) and will be all mapped to it.

If you want to refine the patterns of your control ID assignment, [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/May/04/Whats-New-in-ASPNET-40-Part-Two-WebForms-and-Visual-Studio-Enhancements)'s more about the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Add  `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` to the TextBox.  Asp.net will figure out what to do.